# How long is the default Laravel 4 "string" when creating tables and how to override the default value?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

When you look at this:

```
$table->string('email');
```

What exactly string means? Is it  varchar or tinytext?

How long is the default value?

Where in the source files can I override the value, without using

```
$table->string('email', 100);
```

all the time?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is varchar, and the default length is 255 - as defined in the source code:

```
public function string($column, $length = 255)
```

> Where in the source files can I override the value

You should not modify the source code. If you do, every time you run composer update it will risk being overwritten. You should just define any custom maximum you like each time you define a new string in your code.

Although I would propose to you that unless you have a good reason, using 255 is usually ok.

Comment: Thank you, but can I override it in some helper in my app?

Comment: You could extend the core - but that is a lot of work for such as small thing. Why do you *want* to change it in the first place? http://laravel.com/docs/extending